# Show/hide a certain div when children elements of a different div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want `dropdown-content` to be displayed every time I click on the `dropbtn`. The problem with my current code is that it only works if I only click the spaces inside my `dropbtn` div, but if I click on the elements inside it or the children elements, it doesn't work and `dropdown-content` is still displayed as none.

I tried selecting all the elements inside my `droptbtn` div and used the same conditions to hide/show `dropdown-content` but that too didn't work.

My ultimate goal is to hide/show `dropdown-content` when `dropbtn` div is clicked, regardless if user has clicked its children elements or not.

HTML code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">
        <img src="{{ user.profilePic.url }}" alt="">
        <small><b>{{ user.username }}</b></small>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
        <a href="{%url 'profile'%}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
        <a href="{%url 'logout'%}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
let dropbtn = document.getElementById('dropbtn');
let dropbtn_elem = dropbtn.getElementsByTagName('img, small, i')
let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== dropbtn && dropdown.style.display === "block"){
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
    }
})

dropbtn.onclick = function() {
    if (dropdown.style.display === "block") {
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dropdown.style.display = "block";
    }
}

dropbtn_elem.onclick = function() {
    if (dropdown.style.display === "block") {
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dropdown.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: just set `pointer-events: none` to all children of `.dropbtn`.

Comment: I said to its `children` not the `.dropbtn` itself. It is not working because you set `pointer-events: none` to `.dropbtn`

Comment: I selected all of its children elements in css and now it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @kunal-tanwar suggested use

```
#dropbtn *
{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Sometimes this method won't work, when you need register clicks on children, in that case use `element.closest()` to check if the `element` or it's ancestors match the selector:

```js
let dropbtn = document.getElementById('dropbtn');
let dropbtn_elem = dropbtn.getElementsByTagName('img, small, i')
let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest("#dropbtn") || dropdown.style.display != "block")
    return;

   dropdown.style.display = "none";
})

dropbtn.onclick = function() {
    if (dropdown.style.display === "block") {
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dropdown.style.display = "block";
    }
}

dropbtn_elem.onclick = function() {
    if (dropdown.style.display === "block") {
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dropdown.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">
        <img src="{{ user.profilePic.url }}" alt="">
        <small><b>{{ user.username }}</b></small>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
        <a href="{%url 'profile'%}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
        <a href="{%url 'logout'%}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```